# Removing element from array in class method

Tags: javascript, class

I was working on a hackerrank problem and test cases showed that something was wrong with my 'remove' method. I always got undefined instead of true/false.

I know splice returns array of deleted elements from an array. When I console.log inside map, it looked like everything was fine when I was deleting first element (I was getting what I expected except true/false). But when 'name' I am deleting is not first element, I didn't get what I expected to get. Could you help me fix this? And of course, I never get true or false...

```js
class StaffList {
    constructor() {
        this.members = [];
    }
    add(name, age) {
        if (age > 20) {
            this.members.push(name)                 
        } else {
            throw new Error("Staff member age must be greater than 20")
        }
    }
    remove(name) {
       this.members.map((item, index) => {
           if(this.members.includes(name)) {
               console.log(name)
               let removed = this.members.splice(item, 1);
               console.log(removed)
               return true;
           } else {
               return false;
           }
       })
    }
    getSize() {
        return this.members.length;
    }
}
let i = new StaffList;
i.add('michelle', 25)
i.add('john', 30);
i.add('michael', 30);
i.add('jane', 26);
i.remove('john');
console.log(i);
```

Comment: Using both map() and splice() incorrectly. As for splice() you are not passing index to splice but rather the element value (`item`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `return` statements are wrapped within `.map()` (which you misuse in this particular case, so you, essentially, build the array of `true`/`false`), but your `remove` method does not return anything.

Instead, I would suggest something, like that:

```
remove(name){
   const matchIdx = this.members.indexOf(name)
   if(matchIdx === -1){
     return false
   } else {
     this.members.splice(matchIdx, 1)
     return true
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the `remove` method, you're using `map` with the array, which runs the function you give as argument for each array element. But I believe you don't want to do that.

Using the example you have bellow, basically what you do there is check if the array contains the name `'john'`, and if so, you delete the first item that appears in the array (which would be `'michelle'`). This happens because the map function will run for every element, starting on the first one, and then you use that `item` to be removed from the array. After that, it returns the function, and no other elements get removed.

So my suggestion is just getting rid of the `map` function and running its callback code directly in the `remove` method (you would need to get the name's index in the array to use the `splice` method).

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear why you need to use iterative logic to remove an item. You can simply use `findIndex()` to get the position of the member in the array. If the `index` is not `-1`, then you can use `Array.prototype.slice(index, 1)` to remove it. See proof-of-concept example below:

```js
class StaffList {
    constructor() {
        this.members = [];
    }
    add(name, age) {
        if (age > 20) {
            this.members.push(name)                 
        } else {
            throw new Error("Staff member age must be greater than 20")
        }
    }
    remove(name) {
      const index = this.members.findIndex(x => x === name);
      if (index !== -1) {
        this.members.splice(index, 1);
      }
    }
    getSize() {
        return this.members.length;
    }
}
let i = new StaffList;
i.add('michelle', 25)
i.add('john', 30);
i.add('michael', 30);
i.add('jane', 26);
i.remove('john');
console.log(i);
```

Comment: `.findIndex(x => x === name)` = `.indexOf(name)`

Comment: and, by the way, your `remove()`-method still doesn't return `true`/`false`

Answer (score 1):

Use a `filter` method instead of `map` it's more elegant and you can return the rest of the array as well instead of `true` or `false` unless the problem you're working on requires `true` of `false` specifically.
You could write something like this:

```
remove(name) {
   if (!this.members.some(el => el === name)) return false;
   this.members = this.members.filter(item => item !== name);
   return true;
}
```